# Log4j2 : NoClassDefFoundError : LogManager

Tags: java, log4j, noclassdeffounderror

I was trying out Log4j2 so I created a Java project in eclipse. My code is same as [Log4j2 Manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/manual/configuration.html) Automatic Configuration part. I have added log4j-api-2.17.2.jar and log4j-core-2.17.2.jar in the classpath. When I run the application I get following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
    at demo.one.MainClass.<clinit>(MainClass.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

I have checked some related questions but didn't find those useful.

Comment: Is `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` present in your project (including libraries)?

Comment: Don't understand your question properly. I have the api and core jar files in referenced library.

Comment: But the class which cannot be found?

Comment: How exactly do you run your code? Please provide full command lines? (Reason is that this can be explained by an incorrect classpath argument)

Comment: I ran the code from eclipse. I selected "Run as Java Application" and chose MyApp class.

Comment: LogManager should be in log4j-api, so I would have a closer look at how exactly you added the jar files to the classpath.   You might have missed a step.

Comment: So here was the problem, both jar files were in .classpath file as "module" because I added them as modulepath in eclipse. But jars have to added as "classpath". So in .classpath file jars should look like below: 

```<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/User/Documents/Jars/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/User/Documents/Jars/log4j-core-2.17.2.jar"/>```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use maven, make sure to include [Log4j core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core) to the project:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, it's a NoClassDefFoundError, that means your JRE is not able to find out the necessary jar(class) artifact holding definition for org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.
Look for differences between build and runtime classpaths.

Answer (score 0):

how did u run the code?
If from terminal, you might want to add `maven-shade-plugin`
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html

Comment: Please don't just link to a tool or library. Instead, also include details about what it does, how it addresses the OP's question, and ideally how to use it to solve the specifics of the case. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include this information?**

Comment: Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76015329/11748454) for the 3 resource transformers required by Log4j 2.x.